# angularfire set / update user database

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I am new to Angular.
I have a page for user to edit their profile information.
I am facing issues with .set() and .update(), but things works fine when using .push().

**edit-profile.html**

```
  <ion-navbar color="primary">
    <ion-title>Edit Profile</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-input floating placeholder="User name" [(ngModel)]="user.username"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-input floating placeholder="age" [(ngModel)]="user.age"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>

  <button ion-button clear block (click)="saveProfile()">Save</button>
</ion-content>
```

**edit-profile.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { User } from '../../models/user/user.model';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-edit-profile',
  templateUrl: 'edit-profile.html',
})
export class EditProfilePage {

  user = {} as User;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
    public navParams: NavParams,
    private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    private afdb: AngularFireDatabase) { }

  saveProfile(user: User) {

    this.afAuth.authState.take(1).subscribe(auth => {
      this.afdb.list(`user/${auth.uid}`).push(this.user)
        .then(() => this.navCtrl.setRoot('TabsPage'));
    });
  }

}
```

[image]

- node v.8.94
- npm 5.6.0
- cordova@8.0.0
- ionic@3.19.1
- rxjs@5.5.6
- angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.6
- firebase@4.9.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved

```
this.afdb.list(`user`).update(auth.uid, this.user)
```